# Rotate geometry, fingers of a hand

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I managed to build a hand with vertices and faces, since i can't use cubeGeometry on this assignment.

[JSFiddle of hand](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagoponte/yyhk4/9/)

But now i need to rotate the "fingers" to make it look like it's closing the hand.
The hand will close with a keypress.

How do make it animate all fingers together using a onKeyDown event?
And go make it go back to original position using another key?

i "found out" the intermediary stages of the finger closing:

```
//rotate stage 1
finger1Mesh.rotation.x = 0.5 ;
finger1Mesh.position.z = -10;
//rotate stage 2
finger1Mesh.rotation.x = 1.25;
finger1Mesh.position.y = 100;
finger1Mesh.position.z = -10;
//rotate stage 3
finger1Mesh.rotation.x = 2.5 ;
finger1Mesh.position.y = 110;
finger1Mesh.position.z = -10;
//rotate stage 4
finger1Mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI;
finger1Mesh.position.y = 120;
finger1Mesh.position.z = 20;
```

If you remove this code from the JSFiddle i posted, all the fingers will be open.

I'm doing this on a try-and-error approach. If there's an easier way, please tell me.

Comment: Are you sure this is the approach you're supposed to be taking? You're effectively still building cubes out of faces. My suspicion is that you're supposed to be looking at something like THREE.SkinnedMesh. Get a copy of Learning Three.js and take a look at Chapter 9 Example 12. The example code i available here on Github: https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-09/12-bones-manually.html

Comment: I don't think so. He didn't teach us about Bones. But i'll confirm with him tonight.